# Duda sobre los punteros en C

Tags: c

Alguien podria explicarme lo de los punteros en C? Intento hacer un programa pero no acabo de entender el concepto de puntero.

Comment: y que has investigado?

Comment: y como los estas implementando?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Te contaré la idea básica. Un puntero es una variable que en lugar de contener un dato, contiene la dirección de memoria en la que hay un dato.

Una dirección de memoria no deja de ser un número, por lo que un puntero en realidad contiene un número. Si `p` es una variable de tipo puntero, entonces `p` es ese número (una dirección de memoria). Para acceder al dato apuntado por `p` debes usar la sintaxis `*p`.

Por ejemplo, `*p=3` guardaría un 3 en la dirección a la que `p` apunta. Para que esa asignación sea válida, el tipo del dato (3) y el tipo de puntero deben coincidir, es decir, en este caso `p` debería ser un puntero a entero, lo cual se declara como `int *p;`

Pero aunque los tipos coincidan, *además* el número que hay en `p` (la dirección a que apunta) ha de ser un número válido (una dirección de memoria en la que tengas permiso para escribir o leer). Típicamente será la dirección de otra variable de tu programa (la dirección de `n` se puede obtener con `&n`, por lo que `p=&n;` sería una forma correcta de inicializar `p`, si `n` es del tipo correcto), o bien una dirección creada dinámicamente a través de una llamada a `malloc()` (en este caso la inicialización sería `p=(int *)malloc(sizeof(int))` por ejemplo.

Esto es lo más básico sobre punteros. Más cosas que quedan sin contar es su uso como parámetro, o la aritmética de punteros que te permite iterar sobre varios elementos del mismo tipo (arrays) usando un puntero para acceder a ellos. Pero extenderme en todo eso sería repetir conceptos que ya están en libros y tutoriales.